# PHP, MYSQL & JSON

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Ok, So I'm using AJAX to pull some information from my MYSQL database and put it onto the screen. The thing is I cannot understand JSON for the life of me. Can you suggest any tutorials or anything that will help?

I mean I get that I can encode my query via JSON but I guess it's the javascript side I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my quick tutorial:

JSON is a means for expressing data for arrays, objects, and their contents. It has nothing to do with object behaviour (methods).

```
<?php
class Test {
    public $hello = 'hello';
    public $something = array('hello1', 'hello2');

    public __construct() {

    }

    public void printHello() {
        echo $this->hello;
    }
}
?>
```

This class would in JSON would look like:

```
var obj = {
   "hello": "hello",
   "something": ["hello1", "hello2"] 
};
```

As you can see, JSON is similar to maps in a lot of languages (key/value pairs). You can also see, that only data is represented. JSON is also shorthand for JavaScript builtins. For example, this previous object can be written in JavaScript like so.

```
   var obj = new Object();
   obj.hello = "hello";
   obj.something = new Array("hello1", "hello2");
```

Hope this gives you a little idea of what JSON is about.

Comment: But how would you pull those values once their in JSON? print(obj[0]); ?

Comment: I'm not following. Are you asking how to get those values back into php objects?

Comment: oh no sorry, not pull. I mean print the values to HTML or anything.

Answer (score 1):

First, read this: http://www.json.org/js.html

Then, practice with this: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can read about using JSON in JavaScript at [the Mozilla docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/json).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this short example will help you: http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/26-html-and-javascript/89-jquery-ajax-json-and-php.

[jQuery docs - getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

How to use JSON (updated with example)

http://www.javascriptkata.com/2009/09/16/how-to-use-json-updated-with-example/

Comment: Thanks but that's the JQuery version, i barely understand AJAX(JQuery) as it is.